# How to optimize out default if-branch

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, icc, gcc4.9

I have the following bit of code. Given how foo is being invoked, what compiler arguments can be given the GCC and Clang to optimize the if-statement out like icc does?

**Code:**

```
#include <cstdlib>

int foo(int i, bool b = false)
{
   if (b) ++i;
   return ++i;
}

int boo(int i)
{
   return ++i;
}

static const bool global_b = false;
int goo(int i, bool b = global_b)
{
   if (b) ++i;
   return ++i;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i = atoi(argv[1]);
  return 2 * foo(i) + 3 * boo(i) + 7 * goo(i);
}
```

**GCC 4.9 -O2 disassembly:**

```
foo(int, bool):
   cmp   sil, 1
   sbb   edi, -1
   lea   eax, [rdi+1]
   ret

goo(int, bool):
   cmp   sil, 1
   sbb   edi, -1
   lea   eax, [rdi+1]
   ret

boo(int):
   lea   eax, [rdi+1]
   ret
```

**Clang 3.4 -O2 disassembly:**

```
foo(int, bool):
   movzbl %sil, %eax
   leal   1(%rdi,%rax), %eax
   ret
goo(int, bool):
   movzbl %sil, %eax
   leal   1(%rdi,%rax), %eax
   ret
boo(int):
   leal  1(%rdi), %eax
   ret
```

**IntelCC 13 -O2 disassembly:**

```
foo(int, bool):
 incl %edi
 movl %edi, %eax
 ret
goo(int):
 incl %edi
 movl %edi, %eax
 ret       
boo(int):
 incl %edi
 movl %edi, %eax
 ret
```

Templatising *foo* we get the following:

```
template <typename T>
T foo_t(T i, bool b = false)
{
   if (b) ++i;
   return ++i;
}
```

**GCC 4.9 is implicitly inlined:**

```
add eax, 1
```

Comment: Um, ICC's codegen is just...wrong.

Comment: @TC: could you please elaborate? The results come from: http://gcc.godbolt.org

Comment: ICC's generated code doesn't check the bool argument at all. Since `foo` has external linkage, and thus can be called with `true` as the second parameter by something in a different translation unit, that codegen is simply incorrect.

Comment: Did you try `gcc -O3`?

Comment: @firda: yes, here it is: foo(int, bool):
 cmp sil, 1
 sbb edi, -1
 lea eax, [rdi+1]
 ret

Comment: Mark it with `inline` or evern `__attribute__((always_inline))`. I personally use macro `#define finline __attribute__((always_inline)) inline` ...and alternatives for other compilers. (`f` as force)

Comment: What program did you test with `foo_t`? is the asm you show 1 line extracted from main? If so you were getting the same without templates. Making it a template is equivalent to marking it `inline`, when what you need is `static`.

Answer (score 4):

Intel's compiler is wrong. Without an option like gcc's `-fwhole-program` (which automatically marks all functions but `main` as `static`, i.e. local to this translation unit), we don't know if `foo` is called from another translation unit, so the compiler cannot assume that it is always called with a second argument equal to `false`.

Comment: foo is in the current translation unit. if foo was a template where int was a typename in another header the optimization works.

Comment: `foo<X>` where `X` is in an *anonymous namespace* may roughly make the function static (can't refer to it from any other TU) and the transformation valid, not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: When it's a template, the compiler can say "Nobody else will call this function", since templates can't be used across compilation units, but `foo` is possible to call from some other compilation unit. Make it `static`, and that will go away. Also, if the code is actually inlined, the compiler will resolve constant value of `b` in the inlining phase.

Comment: @MatsPetersson You can use templates across TU (like inline functions), that's why we so often put them into headers.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: No, the reason we put them in headers is that the compiler will NOT use templates outside of the current TU. Instead, you have to include the source of the template function into that TU via a header file.

Comment: One thing the compiler could do (and at least gcc sometimes does) is *clone* the function, create a new function foo_false that assumes that the second argument is false, and replace some calls to foo with calls to foo_false. But that does not affect foo itself.

Comment: @MatsPetersson And that same template will be used in several TUs, and per the one definition rule, they will be unified at link time so you better not "optimize" one of them based on assumptions done in only one TU.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I think the compiler can "assume the function is inline", which means that unless its address is taken, this instance of the function won't be called from anywhere else. Yes, it means the function can't be made global and reused elsewhere, and is one of the reason why large functions in templates can lead to very bloated code if the function is used in many TUs. But the very fact that you need the source in each TU, and can't do `extern int foo<int, bool>(int i, bool b)` is a sign that the compiler doesn't "link" to other copies of the template.

Comment: "assume the function is inline" means the compiler can inline or clone it (and tweak that clone however it likes), not break it. The term "instance of a function" is a bit misleading, there is only one real function foo. You can look at what your linker does, it takes a number of *weak* copies of the inline function and keeps only one (so they have the same address and don't bloat the program). Also, there is `extern template` and explicit instantiations.

Answer (score 1):

Have inline qualifier, and also what's the point of incrementing a local variable that has been passed by value? Here's an optimised version:

```
#include <cstdlib>

inline int foo(int i, bool b = false)
{
   // i is passed by value, no point incrementing it
   //if (b) ++i; 
   //return ++i;
   return (b)? i+2 : i+1;
}

inline int boo(int i)
{
   // i is passed by value, no point incrementing it
   return i+1;//++i;
}

static const bool global_b = false;
inline int goo(int i, bool b = global_b)
{
   // i is passed by value, no point incrementing it
   //if (b) ++i;
   //return ++i;
   return (b)? i+2 : i+1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i = atoi(argv[1]);
  return 2 * foo(i) + 3 * boo(i) + 7 * goo(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting `foo` body as `return i+1+b;`.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned `-fwhole-program` is key to success.

Also, you can define your function as static (inline will work too):

```
static int foo(int i, bool b = false)
{
   if (b) ++i;
   return ++i;
}
```

this will generate only:

```
add eax, 1
```

Comment: the problem is that this is a toy example, the actual function is quite large and the compiler seems to not want to inline it.

Comment: @GellyRistor if it is large function and you know that some variables will not change value - just get rid of such variables and related conditions, if you cannot tell this - compiler will not help

Answer (score 0):

OP only tells part of the story :).

`gcc -O2` actually inlines all of the function calls and `main` looks like this:

```
main:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movq    8(%rsi), %rdi
    movl    $10, %edx
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    call    strtol
    addl    $1, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    leal    0(,%rax,8), %edx
    leal    (%rdx,%rax,4), %eax
    ret
```